# Low quality in tex->dvi->ps->pdf

Tags: graphics, pdf, eps, dvi

I took a screenshot an then saved as EPS using photoshop. This EPS looks well as it's original source.
I use the following code to insert the image:

```
\begin{figure}[H]\begin{center}
 \centering
  \captionsetup{justification=centering}
  \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{pictures/proposal/aaaida_use_case}
  \caption{lorem ipsum \label{fig:network-architecture}}
\end{center}\end{figure}
```

When I compile the tex to dvi, then ps and finally pdf, the resulting image included in the document has a very poor quality, like a JPEG when you save it several times (recompression with quality loss)

Instead of this, if I compile directly to dvi and then pdf it shows nice.

And if instead of saving to EPS I save the image to PDF, using PDFLatex also looks fine.

So I don't understand why the PS step is loosing quality (image recompression).

Finally I don't understand pretty well the differences between DVI->PS->PDF and DVI->PDF on terms of the resulting document.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need EPS while you can save your screenshot in PNG which can be imported by `pdflatex`?

Comment: I use a template created by my university, which uses several EPS files in order to add the logos and different pictures. Using pdflatex fails with that EPS images, I found that pdflatex don't work with EPS.

Comment: But you can convert your existing EPS to PDF first and then use pdflatex.

Comment: Ok, that's true! On the other side, I will need to include vector images, exporting to PDF will be OK then? Thank you!

Comment: I think `graphicx` package will convert EPS to PDF automatically if you use `pdflatex`. Try it if you don't know. :-)

Answer (score 4):

For the PS -> PDF step you can use `ps2pdf` with options to suppress resampling and lossily compressing images `-dAutoFilterColorImages=false` and `-dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode`. (On windows, you may have to replace the `=` by `#`).

Comment: Thanks! I'm finally using pdflatex directly, but it's interesting to have the answer here. Thanks!